# How to update queryParams in url?

Tags: angular

I have this route in url :

```
localhost:8080/test/local/evidention/1248/161/1?procesId=12
```

Now what i need is on click to change this /1 into /2 . Any suggestion how can i update that queryParm ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's router ships with the directive routerLink which allows you to do the following thing by using **routerLink** and **queryParamsHandling**:

```
<a [routerLink]="../2" queryParamsHandling="preserve"></a>.
```

The /1 you are using there is not a query parameter so you just navigate to that url manually using routerLink. If you needed to change the procesId from 12 to something else then you can do this:

```
<a [queryParams]="{procesId: 13}" queryParamsHandling="merge"></a>
```